# Локальные и внутренние классы

Tags: java, классы

Возник вопрос - какая существует разница между локальными и внутренними классами?

Comment: как я понял, локальные - это находящиеся внутри блоков?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Внутренние классы-члены ассоциируются не с самим внешним классом, а с его экземпляром, т.е. каждый экземпляр внутреннего класса связан с экземпляром его окружающего класса. Вы не можете создать экземпляр внутреннего класса без привязки к экземпляру внешнего класса. То есть сперва должен быть создан экземпляр внешнего класса, а только затем уже вы можете создать экземпляр внутреннего класса.

```
public class Outer {
    private int outInt = 10;

    class  InnerClass {

        int getOutInt() {
            return outInt;
        }
    }

    InnerClass getInnerClass() {
        return  new InnerClass();
    }
}
```

psvm:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception  { 
        Outer outer = new Outer();
        Outer.InnerClass innerClass = outer.getInnerClass();
        System.out.println("getOutInt = " + innerClass.getOutInt());
}
```

Как и другие поля класса, вложенные классы могут быть объявлены как `private`, `public`, `protected`, или `package private`.

При этом не статические классы имеют доступ к полям содержащего класса, даже если они объявлены как `private`. Статические же **не** имеют доступ к членам внешнего класса.

```
public class OuterClass { 
    public void method() { ... } 

    public class InnerClass { 
        public void method() { ... } 

        public void anotherMethod() { 
            method(); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Вызов `method()` из `anotherMethod` обратится к методу класса `InnerClass`. Для обращения к методу обрамляющего класса необходимо использовать конструкцию вида `OuterClass.this.method()`

---

Локальные классы определяются в блоке Java кода. На практике чаще всего объявление происходит в методе некоторого другого класса. Хотя объявлять локальный класс можно внутри статических и нестатических блоков инициализации.
Локальный класс имеет доступ к членам класса, в котором он объявлен

```
public class Outer {
    String strO = "Outer";

    void printVars() {
        final int i = 10;

        class Local {
            String strL = "Local";

            void printLocal() {
                System.out.println("strL: " + strL);
                System.out.println("strO: " + strO);
                System.out.println("finalInt: " + i);
            }
        }

        Local local = new Local();
        local.printLocal();
    }
}
```

psvm:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception  {
        Outer o = new Outer();
        o.printVars();
}
```

Также, локальный класс имеет доступ к локальным переменным. Локальные классы имеют доступ только к переменным, объявленным как `final`.

Однако начиная с  `Java SE 8`, локальные классы имеют доступ к финальным (final) локальным переменным и параметрам, а также к неизменяемым (effectively final) переменным, т.е. к переменным, которые не изменились с момента инициализации.

Т.е. в предыдущем примере можно было написать не `final int i = 10;`, а просто `int i = 10;`, при условии, что далее не будет происходить с ней ничего, даже банальных `i = 11;`. В таком случае `System.out.println("finalInt: " + i);` выдаст ошибку.

Собственно, ограничения локальных классов:

- Они видны только в пределах блока, в котором объявлены;
- Они не могут быть объявлены как `private`, `public`, `protected` или `static`;
- Они не могут иметь внутри себя статических объявлений (полей, методов, классов); исключением являются константы (`static final`);

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться

Comment: @Aлексей Шиманский, не могу понять строчку  **Outer.InnerClass innerClass = outer.getInnerClass();** , здесь применив метод **getInnerClass()**  к экземпляру класса **Outer** мы создаем экземпляр **InnerClass** с названием **innerClass**, а что такое  **Outer.InnerClass**?

Comment: Это тип переменной....... т.е. Обычно мы пишем `SomeClass myVar = new SomeClass();` ..... То есть создадим экземпляр класса `SomeClass` типа `SomeClass` ..........в случае выше, мы хотим создать экземпляр класса `InnerClass` типа `InnerClass`........Экземпляр мы создаем за счет `outer.getInnerClass();` а вот тип как взять? сразу `InnerClass` мы не сможем написать, ибо он скрыт во внешнем классе... А значит мы должны обратиться так сказать через посредника, т.е. через внешний класс, чтоб "вытащить" данный тип...

Comment: Вы написали, что **локальний класс имеет доступ к локальным переменным**, это переменные внешнего класса? Ведь в Вашем примере **void printLocal()** работает с **strO** **Outer** класса?

Comment: локальний класс имеет доступ к локальным переменным - это я про  `final int i = 10;`. Но к переменным и методам внешнего класса он тоже имеет доступ

Comment: огромное Вам спасибо, очень доступно объяснили материал