# Создание метода в методе main

Tags: java

Почему компилятор выдает ошибку?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int abc = 5;

        public void run(){

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Там ошибку подсказывает idea: мол нет ; (точки с запятой). Выложил код.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Потому что в Java нельзя объявлять метод в методе

Answer (score 6):

В `java` нельзя создавать вложенные методы, но никто не запрещает объявить лямбда фукцию:

```
Consumer<String> fun = name -> System.out.println(String.format("hello %s", name));
fun.accept("John");
```

Answer (score 2):

В Java нельзя создать метод в методе, но если по какой-то причине очень хочется, то можно создать локальный класс с его собственными методами. Примерно так:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int abc = 5;

        class RunClass {
            public void run(int n) {
                System.out.println(n);
            }
        }

        RunClass runclass = new RunClass();
        runclass.run(abc);  
    }
}
```

У локальных классов есть ограничения:

> 1. он имеет доступ только к финальным полям и аргументам обрамляющего метода, а также ко всем полям обрамляющего класса, в том числе  приватным и статическим;
> 2. локальный класс виден и может создаваться только в блоке, в котором описан;
> 3. у локального класса не ставиться модификатор доступа;
> 4. не может иметь статических полей, методов, классов (за исключением финальных);
> 5. локальный класс, объявленный в статическом блоке может обращаться только к статическим полям внешнего класса.

Полезные ссылки:

- [Локальные и внутренние классы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/515940/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B)
- [Вложенные классы в Java](https://habr.com/post/342090/)